# Добавление картинок в SQL базу

Tags: java

Пытаюсь сделать активити где можно добавлять, удалять картинки, а так же сохранять прогресс (удалил или добавил пользователь картинки на экран) Для этого необходима SQL база данных. Нашел уроки как добавлять, просматривать добавленный текст. А как импортировать туда изображения?

Comment: Уточните, какую именно СУБД вы используете. Какой способ доступа к БД используется: ORM или что-то другое?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хранить сами изображения в БД хотя и возможно, но крайне не рекомендуется. Для хранения используется формат `blob`. [Пример с реализацией](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9357943)

Рекомендованный способ - хранить картинки отдельно (внутри проекта, на SD-карте и тд.), а в БД хранить только ссылки на ресурсы, вроде `R.id.image1` (в первом случае) или имена файлов, вроде `image1.png` - во втором. При запросе из БД получаем эту ссылку на картинку,а уже по ней саму картинку.